# How to iterate through a list to create combinations of n successive values and use them independently in Python?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

```py
from PIL import Image
imagen_base = Image.open(imagen_base)
a = Image.open(a)
b = Image.open(b)
c = Image.open(c)
d = Image.open(d)
e = Image.open(e)
f = Image.open(f)
            
lista=[a,b,c,d,e,f]
```

1. First, you would have a base image:

```py
image_base = Image.open (image_base)
```

2. Second, you would have a list of images:

```py
a = Image.open(a)
b = Image.open(b)
c = Image.open(c)
d = Image.open(d)
e = Image.open(e)
f = Image.open(f)
    
list = [a, b, c, d, e, f]
```

3. The objective would be to obtain three new images; place the **ab**, **cd** and **ef** combinations above the base image thanks to the paste function inside the module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i'm understanding your question correctly, you just to find a way to group items N successive items in a list? If so, you could try:

```
combined = []
for idx, val in enumerate(_list):
    if (_list[idx] == 0) | (idx % 2 == 0): 
        combined.append((_list[idx], _list[idx + 1]))
```

Which will return:

```
combined = [(a, b), (c, d), (e, f)]
```

Now, in this example I am using .append() method to put them back into a list for clarity, but you can replace that with whatever functions you require in your task.